# Unable to fetch webspage with Dokku on digitalocean

Tags: dns, digital-ocean, cloudflare, dokku

I'm currently having trouble with hosting with dokku on digitalocean. Everything uploads just fine, all "pre-flight checks" pass and dokku even says that my application was deployed successfully. However when I go to the domain i used for the app [(which is this)](https://kzoltany.me/). I get an error saying webpage isn't available, or since i'm using CloudFlare for DNS it says "Website is offline". I have all the dns servers pointing to CloudFlare and standard dns and the wildcard dns are setup as [so...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFZtP.png)

Happy to add more information if needed.

Answer (score 0):

The domain appears to work for me. Did you get this sorted out?